# Why do Teledesic satellites look so weird? What are these structures and where's the satellite bus?

Tags: design, communication-satellite, antenna

[image: Teledesic satellite drawing]

[source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Teledesic_Satellite.gif) enlarged and sharpened

To my untrained eye I see a weird claw or flower-like antenna array with eight petals in the shape reminiscent of concave dish but not really, that look like they might fold together but not really.

Then there's a stem that extends up to a flat solar panel.

But apart from an the antenna flower and solar panel I'm left asking myself "Where's the <s>beef</s> satellite?"

**Question:** Why do Teledesic satellites look so weird? What are these structures and where's the satellite bus?

How does this "antenna flower" work? Where's the satellite bus?

Comment: Did you find any evidence that this was more than an artists impression? The only satellite they ever launched was used a commercial platform.

Comment: @asdfex ya these are almost always artists impressions, but some are less informed than others. However it's the only image available in Wikipedia's [Teledesic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teledesic) If the answer is "Because they don't look like that" then that's the answer!

Comment: It's weird to think that ~900 satellites was once considered "extremely ambitious".

Comment: @JörgWMittag When you're not your own launch provider, 900 satellites is still considered extremely ambitious.

Comment: It's a satellite which focuses solar energy down to the ground in order to provide sunlight for growing plants, and it's most definitely not a weapon to detonate the minefield between North and South Korea as a pretext for an invasion. It was featured in the popular 2002 documentary "Die Another Day". ([reference](https://jamesbond.fandom.com/wiki/Icarus))

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After a great deal of searching, I found a PDF [here](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.114.4293&rep=rep1&type=pdf&psig=AOvVaw3F9pPhNf7o0nxnjH4u-6Su&ust=1631537225412000), by Mark A Sturza of Teledesic.  There's a basic diagram of the satellite on page 8

[image: Image credit: Teledesic Coporation]

(Image credit: Teledesic Coporation)

There is also the following description:

> The on-orbit configuration of the Teledesic satellite, Figure 8,
> resembles a flower with eight “petals” and a large boom-mounted square
> solar array. The deployed  satellite is 12 m in diameter and the solar
> array is 12 m on each side. Each petal consists of three large panels
> containing the phase-array antennas. The octagonal baseplate also
> supports eight pairs of intersatellite link antennas, the two
> satellite bus structures that house the engineering subsystem
> components, and propulsion thrusters. A third satellite bus structure,
> containing power equipment and additional propulsion thrusters, is
> mounted at the end of the solar array boom. The solar array is
> articulated to point to the sun.

Comment: It's beautiful, and I see now the "two satellite bus structures" are integral to the back of the flower. I'd found the image in [this list](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Communication_satellites) and not on the Teledesic page and was so fascinated by it that I wrote the question. I'm just now finally realizing that the constellation was never launched, and even a single complete satellite may never have been built with this complete configuration.

Comment: Ok, so the image above has as much in common with a real satellite as the typical "design concepts" shown at automobile fairs have with a real car?